# Accessing all the many colors of WPF, but in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, colors

There's a wide variety of colors available when setting colors in XAML in Silverlight, but the options seem limited when dealing with setting colors programmatically.

For example, in Silverlight XAML I can set a Background to "Alice Blue", "Antique White", etc.

But if I try to set that same background in the code-behind, I'm limited to a fairly finite set of colors based on the [Colors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colors_members%28VS.95%29.aspx) class... Black, Blue, Brown...White, Yellow. These come into play with something like:

```
uxPanel.Background = new SolidColorBrush (Colors.Green);
```

I know I can set any color I'd like via RGB values, as in (where colorsString is something like "112345"):

```
var brush = new SolidColorBrush ();
var c = new Color
            {
                A = 0xFF,
                R = Convert.ToByte (colorString.Substring (0, 2), 16),
                G = Convert.ToByte (colorString.Substring (2, 2), 16),
                B = Convert.ToByte (colorString.Substring (4, 2), 16)
            };

brush.Color = c;

return (brush);
```

But how can I tap into the wider variety of color names accessible in XAML or via a style, but set programmatically in my code-behind? Or is this not possible in Silverlight?

Comment: I cant see any difference in WPF both [Colors] and [Brushes] enumerations are pretty much same. I havent checked SL though.

Comment: Yes you are right on Silverlight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question. In my code-behind in XAML I can access colours such as "Antique White" via the Colors object:

```
var c = Colors.AntiqueWhite;
```

It's not a different set of colours from the ones you can access in XAML.

Colours such as AntiqueWhite are available whether I reference [System.Drawing.Color](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.aspx) or [System.Windows.Media.Colors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colors.aspx).

**Edit**

So it looks like you're talking specifically about the [System.Windows.Media.Colors class in Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colors_members(VS.95).aspx), which does indeed give you only a limited set of colours to work with. How odd!

I guess the easiest thing to do is define your own class with the ARGB values from the [MSDN documentation on the WPF version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colors_members.aspx). Something like:

```
public static class ExtraColors
{
    private static Color _antiqueWhite = Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xFA, 0xEB, 0xD7);
    // etc

    public static Color AntiqueWhite { get { return _antiqueWhite; } }
    // etc
}
```

Awkward, I know, but it'll at least get you a readable code-accessible list of those extra colours.

Comment: His question is referring on Silverlight I guess. In Silverlight Colors enumeration is limited at code behind

Comment: Oh wow - you're right. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colors_members(VS.95).aspx

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't realize there was a diff in the accessible colors between WPF and Silverlight. I'll re-tag the question.

Comment: Yeah, that is awkward... and ugly. But it looks like the only way.

Answer (score 2):

Someone at silverlight.net [posted code](http://silverlight.net/forums/p/13225/43867.aspx) to recreate the XAML colors in C#.

Comment: Thanks for the link. You just saved me a whole lot of time.

Comment: Great link, found an archived version of it: http://web.archive.org/web/20090802111212/http://silverlight.net/forums/p/13225/43867.aspx